# Is there a way to add a YouTube API player to leaflet control window?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api, leaflet, youtube-iframe-api

I'm making a leaflet map that contains a geoJSON layer. When a point on the geoJSON layer is clicked, the YouTube video identified in that point (by a "youtube_id" field) opens in a leaflet control window. I would really like to be able to get the playback time of the video, and it seems like the only way to do this is with the [YouTube iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), using their [playback status functions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status).

The way I have the map working now is to add an iframe object to the leaflet control window, similar to how [this tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) works. This works to display the video, but there's no way to get the playback time as the video is playing. Here's the relevant part of my javascript:

```
var geoj = GeoJSON.parse(dat, {Point: ['lat', 'lon']});

var style = {
    radius: 2,
    fillColor: "darkred",
    color: "darkred",
};

var YT_id;

var vidPlayer = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});
vidPlayer.onAdd = function(mymap) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'vidPlayer');
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};

vidPlayer.update = function (vidPopup) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>USGS CMG Video</h4>' + (vidPopup ? '<b>' + vidPopup + '</b><br />' : 'Select a video');
};
vidPlayer.addTo(mymap);

var vidPopup;
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function(e) {
        YT_id = feature.properties.youtube_id;
        vidSec = feature.properties.video_second;
        vidPopup = "<iframe id=\"player1\" src=https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + YT_id + "?start=" + vidSec + "&autoplay=1" + " width=\"600\" height=\"450\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>";
        vidPlayer.update(vidPopup);
        lat = feature.geometry.coordinates[1];
        lng = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
        var marker;
        mymap.on('click', function (e) {
            if (marker) {
                mymap.removeLayer(marker);
            }
            marker = new L.Marker([lat,lng]).addTo(mymap);
        });
        return YT_id;
        console.log(vidSec);
    });
}

var polyline = L.geoJSON(geoj, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, style);
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature;
    }
}).addTo(mymap);

mymap.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());

L.control.scale({position: 'bottomright'}).addTo(mymap);
```

I thought I would be able to easily do this by changing `vidPopup` in the `onEachFeature` function to:

```
vidPopup = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '400',
    width: '534',
    videoID: YT_id,
});
```

(as shown in the YouTube iframe API, kind of), but then nothing happens when I click on the geoJSON points. In my browser's inspector, I can see that the `YT_id` variable is getting populated, but `vidPopup` gets returned as:
`X {b: Jb, a: null, h: null, closure_uid_691267473: 1, g: 1…}` and it looks like the variables aren't getting passed to it.

**Does anyone know how I can either get a video's playback time in an iframe object, or how to add a proper YouTube iframe API to a leaflet control window?** I want to keep the control window rather than a separate html side panel so the map can be seen when no video is playing -- that seemed like the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue and successfully got the youtube-api player to open in a leaflet control window.

Changing the `vidPlayer.onAdd` function to:

```
vidPlayer.onAdd = function(map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'vidPlayer');
    this._div.id = "player";
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};
```

Specifically, adding `this._div.id = "player";`.

Then I changed the `onEachFeature` function to:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
layer.on('click', function(e) {
    YT_id = feature.properties.youtube_id;
    vidSec = feature.properties.video_second;
    lat = feature.geometry.coordinates[1];
    lng = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
    var marker;
    map.on('click', function (e) {
        if (marker) {
            map.removeLayer(marker);
        }
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '236.25',
            width: '420',
            videoId: YT_id,
            playerVars: {
                autoplay: 0,
                start: vidSec,
                rel: 0,
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            }
        });
        marker = new L.Marker([lat,lng]).addTo(map);
    });
    return YT_id;
    console.log(vidSec);
});
}    
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

Just in case someone else runs across this trying to do something similar. It's pretty cool when it works.